# How to avoid cross product while doing the inner join?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena, presto

I working on a use case where I need to join table1 with table2. But since there is a column which needs to be part of the out it is increasing the `sum` of the `tbl2_amt` three times the actual value.

Below are both of my tables - 
Table1 -

```
col1    col2    col3    period  col4    col5    col6    col7    tbl1_amt
20110   dt      0000    202302  tcp             de      otfx    19169.19495
20110   dt      0000    202302  tcp             de      acpy    416134.8921
20110   dt      0000    202302  tcp             de      forx    -114689.5469
```

Table2 -

```
period  col1    col2    col3    col4    tbl2_amt
202302  20110   dt      0000    1711    31172.64171
202302  20110   dt      0000    1290    470.1353638
202302  20110   dt      0000    1208    -157.4978849
202302  20110   dt      0000    8158    18382.71997
202302  20110   dt      0000    1200    388217.7242
202302  20110   dt      0000    1200    290454.7377
202302  20110   dt      0000    1290    9422.588832
202302  20110   dt      0000    1711    505307.5402
202302  20110   dt      0000    1290    9980.002115
202302  20110   dt      0000    1290    139973.5195
202302  20110   dt      0000    0000    513661.3896
202302  20110   dt      0000    1200    138179.7272
202302  20110   dt      0000    1200    7159.475465
202302  20110   dt      0000    1236    268.0203046
202302  20110   dt      0000    1290    -480.3828257
202302  20110   dt      0000    1711    11272.73689
202302  20110   dt      0000    1200    1.057529611
202302  20110   dt      0000    1711    2084.263959
202302  20110   dt      0000    1711    3142.110829
202302  20110   dt      0000    1712    23.19162437
202302  20110   dt      0000    8307    11835.60702
202302  20110   dt      0000    1057    1230.964467
202302  20110   dt      0000    1903    271644.247
202302  20110   dt      0000    1290    2470.642978
202302  20110   dt      0000    1057    46684.64467
202302  20110   dt      0000    1290    23518.40102
202302  20110   dt      0000    1290    66276.70262
202302  20110   dt      0000    1290    244284.5812
202302  20110   dt      0000    1903    105582.0749
202302  20110   dt      0000    1290    196.4890017
202302  20110   dt      0000    1208    891.4974619
202302  20110   dt      0000    1711    288288.1557
202302  20110   dt      0000    1200    13.21912014
202302  20110   dt      0000    1200    2310.7022
202302  20110   dt      0000    1290    23006.66244
202302  20110   dt      0000    1185    32263.95939
202302  20110   dt      0000    1200    55201.96701
202302  20110   dt      0000    1299    156910.4484
202302  20110   dt      0000    1711    161.178088
202302  20110   dt      0000    1290    308384.6975
202302  20110   dt      0000    1057    3162.182741
202302  20110   dt      0000    1290    694.4585448
202302  20110   dt      0000    1200    262519.9979
202302  20110   dt      0000    1711    469633.0372
```

I wrote below sql query to achieve the same  -

```
Select 
    tbl1.period, 
    tbl1.col1, 
    tbl1.col2, 
    tbl1.col3, 
    tbl1.col4, 
    tbl1.col5, 
    tbl1.col6, 
    tbl1.col7, 
    tbl2.col4, 
    sum(tbl2_amt) 
from 
    tbl1 
join tbl2 
on tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1
and tbl1.col2 = tbl2.col2
and tbl1.col3 = tbl2.col3
and tbl1.period = tbl2.period
group by tbl1.period, tbl1.col1, tbl1.col2, tbl1.col3, tbl1.col4, tbl1.col5, tbl1.col6, tbl1.col7, tbl2.col4
```

In this it is increasing the `sum(tbl2_amt)` to 3 times the actual value.

How can I get the `tbl2.col4` and `tbl1.col7` and also the `sum(tbl2_amt)` in such a way that the sum is not increased and i can get the rows for both `tbl1.col7` and `tbl2.col4`?

Comment: It would help to explicitly make an example of what you expect in the Select. It is a bit unclear (at least to me) what is your goal here.

Comment: I want all sum to be non-repeating. Having said that, it should result the same number if i just do select sum(tbl2_amt) from tbl2 after joining the two tables

Comment: So do the sum before joining the tables - this is almost always the solution because summing over joins will be subject to multiplication.

Comment: Tried that as well. Still it was multiplying the sum by 3.

Comment: If you aggregate before joining, then the aggregated number cant  be multiplied by the subsequent join. However the join may repeat rows from the aggregated subquery, and you can get `unwanted repetition` of the aggregated number. (The number itself isn't multiplied, just repeated.) If this happens you need to take deliberate action(s) to solve that repetition.

Answer (score 1):

If you perform an aggregation over a dataset that involves one or more joins, then that aggregation is subject to possible multiplication due to the way joins work. To avoid this, aggregate the source table(s) **before joining**, e.g. If you sum table2 before joining to table1 you will get the following result:

```
select
    period, col1, col2, col3, sum(tbl2_amt) as tbl2_amt
from table2
group by
    period, col1, col2, col3
```

| period | col1 | col2 | col3 | tbl2_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202302 | 20110 | dt | 0000 | 4445702.220854321 |

So, if you then join that result to table1, you will get **unwanted repitition** (not multiplication) like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | period | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | tbl1_amt | tbl2_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20110 | dt | 0000 | 202302 | tcp | *null* | de | acpy | 416134.89210 | 4445702.220854321 |
| 20110 | dt | 0000 | 202302 | tcp | *null* | de | otfx | 19169.19495 | **4445702.220854321** |
| 20110 | dt | 0000 | 202302 | tcp | *null* | de | forx | -114689.54690 | **4445702.220854321** |

This is because there is no shared column - such as `col7` - that would align the table2 data to just a single row of table1. To suppress the **unwanted repitition** you need to provide a way to align a single row of aggregated data of table2 to a single row in table1. For this I suggest you use `row_number() over()` like this:

```
select
   t1.*, t2.tbl2_amt
from (
  select
      *
    , row_number() over(partition by period,col1,col2,col3 order by tbl1_amt desc) as rn
  from table1
  ) AS t1
left join (
    select
        period, col1, col2, col3, sum(tbl2_amt) as tbl2_amt
    from table2
    group by
        period, col1, col2, col3
  ) AS t2 ON t1.period = t2.period
         AND t1.col1 = t2.col1
         AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
         AND t1.col3 = t2.col3
         AND t1.rn = 1
```

**Result** without the unwanted repetition

| col1 | col2 | col3 | period | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | tbl1_amt | rn | tbl2_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20110 | dt | 0000 | 202302 | tcp | *null* | de | acpy | 416134.89210 | 1 | **4445702.220854321** |
| 20110 | dt | 0000 | 202302 | tcp | *null* | de | otfx | 19169.19495 | 2 | *null* |
| 20110 | dt | 0000 | 202302 | tcp | *null* | de | forx | -114689.54690 | 3 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_KpXiNhV)

**Alternatively** also aggregate table1 so that it has only rows that match `period, col1, col2, col3`, which will require you to decide what to do with other table1 columns such as `col7` (e.g. omit from final result, or use the max() etc.)

Comment: Can we split the values in a way such that values of `tbl2_amt` is distributed as per the `col7` ? Having said that, if we can somehow manage to assign different values for each one of the values of `col7` and resultant is exactly `4445702` that'll solve the problem and we don't have to deal with the `nulls`. Is that possible?

Comment: Take a look at this - https://dbfiddle.uk/wjV-EY65 - does this help solve the new step?